# Is there anyway to close iphone app just like user press the menu key?

Tags: iphone, background

Is there anyway to close iphone app just like user press the menu key?
I already know exit(0) , it works. But user experience not good, I want to scale the window first and then close the app, just like user press the menu key. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: no. the home button is the way to close/minimize apps. Period.

Comment: Are you want to close app from app manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Apple don't allow it. It's very poor user experience for an app to just exit even if it does look like they've pressed the home button. The user is in control of what happens and when an app exits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to close the iPhone app just like user presses the Home Key, But Apple strictly forbids to use this. Anyways here is the code:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] suspend];`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this, and quite honestly, there really isn't any good reason to do this. Users expect to control when the app closes, period.

What are you trying to gain by closing the app anyway?